# Differentiate intergral function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I found this equation when I read article (Cooperation among Competitors: Some Economics of Payment Card Associations by Jean Tirole), $$\int ^ \infty _x (y+const)dF(y)$$
where $F(y)$ is CDF.

He differentiated the above function with respect to $x$, and get $x=$constants.

I tried to solve by myself, but it seemed beyond my level. Can anyone please help me explain how the paper get $x$ explicitly?

Sorry I should have mentioned that he took First orde condition to find $x$ value that maximises the intergral equation.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a link to this paper/article ?

Comment: Sorry, but your English is barely understandable. You should try to reformulate your question. Otherwise people will not see what you want exactly.

Comment: @jibounet I don't think I am allowed to post the paper here, but I wrote the title of it.

Comment: @Karl I want to get a function like $x= constant variables $ where const's were the variables written in the paper. Hope you understand, and I edited as well... hope others understand, too

Comment: @user1292919, still very unclear due to insufficient information and your peculiar English and mathematical nomenclature. What you mean with _constantvariables_ ? You can't expect that people try to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question based on my interpretation that what we want is:

$max_x \space \space  \space  \int_x^\infty(y+C)dF(y) $

where $C$ is some constant. There is a simple formula for solving these types of problems. [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

This gives us a FOC of $-(x+C)f(x)=0$

where $f(x)$ is the PDF. If $f(x)>0$ for all $x$; that is, the distribution has positive density everywhere, then we get $x=-C$